# Making content in mobile app dynamic

Tags: java, iphone, ios, jakarta-ee, rest

I have made an iphone application that uses a SQLite database which is pre-populated with questions/answers. Each time I want to correct/add questions to the database I have to update the application and submit it to Apple. I have just recently begun to understand some of the JAX-RS API and I have made the questions etc available with REST and expose them as XML. So what I want now is to use the data from the web instead of the fixed database but I have some questions:

- Is REST and the way I describe a "valid" way of doing it?
- I need the questions to be available offline so I thought of downloading the
  document to the device and check periodically if a newer document is
  avalible and download that.

Probably stupid questions but I have not done much web services before so I any help and thoughs would be much appriciated :=)

Comment: If I understood correctly, the way the app "Exoplanet" solved your issue is, they pop that little red dot alert on top of the app whenever the document containing the planets (in your case, your Q/A) changes. Then the application knows it should go and fetch it, and store the content in the phone SQLite DB.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to have a database (in database read: "A chunk of data stored any way you like, be it in plaintext, xml, or sql") in a server to store your questions.
- You need to have an interface to query those questions.

  - A simple (but not very optimized) idea is, to store that database in xml format and make the app periodically (or by user input) grab that xml and parse it.
  - A more complex and better approach is for the app to say "when" it last retrieved questions and provide only a xml with the differences.
  - Your REST approach is fine and could be one of the methods I describe above (you use REST to return it the "simple" way or the "more complex" way. But if you don't need any authentication, you might not want all that overhead. In the end, that's up to you and your needs.
- Parse that file (I'm using XML as example, but you can use JSON, CSV, whatever)
- Store the data in your device.

  - If you're using the "simple" approach, you could erase the entire database and recreate it using the xml
  - If you're using the "more complex" approach, you should just add what you get, since your server SHOULD provide only new questions

Pitfalls:

- Your database needs NOT to be inside the application bundle or you won't be able to write to it (you can only write to it on simulator, not on device)
- You should weight carefully on how to store those questions on the device (if it's an iOS only app, I recommend CoreData)

If you want to display that "red ball" with a number on it (in this case, the number of updates) in your app icon (that's called "badge"), you should use notifications, you'd need to register client the identifier in your site database and, every time there's an update, you should notify each client. That's not trivial, and I belive you should first implement the solution where the app goes search for data before going the other way around.

If you want to learn more about notifications, you could use:

- [Official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)
- [A fine tutorial I've used once](http://maniacdev.com/2011/05/tutorial-ios-push-notification-services-for-beginners/)

Be aware that that's not set in stone. There are other approaches (there *should* be anyway), but that's the workflow that I use when I need updating of a client's database.

Hope it points you in the right direction. Feel free to ask for clarification (if need be).

Answer (score 0):

So answers:

-Yes, it is good way of work, you can use web to upload newest
   data. You can do it in 2 ways:

1)  Upload just new questions and    add them to existing sqlite
    database for your application. But you    should know, that database
    must be placed in Documents directory    instead of your application
    Bundle. Sample code you can check here.

```
        BOOL success;
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
        self.imagesPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images"];

//Check if you have local copy of your database
        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:imagesPath])
        {
        NSError *error;
            if (![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:imagesPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES 
                          attributes:NULL error:&error])
            {
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error cannot create a directory %@", imagesPath);
            }
        }



success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];

//If you have no local copy, than copy default database, which you have added to project
//Instead of this you can also download database from internet.     
        if (!success)
        {
            // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
            NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
            success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
            if (!success) {
                NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
```

2)  You can download whole sqlite database and replace existing. It's
    quite easy, but remember, that you should use more
        traffic in this    case.

- Yes, just store your local database in documents directory, and
  update when you needed.